# Cross-domain cookie authentication trouble WebApi ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-identity

I want to make ajax request from MVC site to WebApi using cookie authorization.
BUT
I've stuck into trouble.

```
ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal
```

**is null**. It seems it cannot recognize cookies, unless it exists in request.
I have two applications
1 - MVC the main
2 - WebApi additional 
MVC requests WebApi. Both use common Identity Users.

Here is my implementation

1. Registration for IAppBuilder

   ```
       public static void Register(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           app.CreatePerOwinContext(MyDbContext.Create);
           app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
           app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
           {
               AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
               CookieName = ".AspNet.Cookies",
               CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never,
               AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
           });

           app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
       }
   ```
2. My ApplicationManager is:

   ```
   public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser> {
   public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store)
   {
   }

   public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
   {
       var appDbContext = context.Get<MyDbContext>();
       var appUserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(appDbContext));
       return appUserManager;
   } }
   ```
3. The same machineKeys in WebApi and MVC

   <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="F7F..."
   validation="SHA1" validationKey="DD2..." />
4. The controller covered with Authorize attribute

   ```
   [Authorize]
   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
   public sealed class BalanceController : ApiController ...
   ```

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

The CORS spec says that if you enable `SupportCredentials` you are not allowed to set `origins` to `"*"`. See the paragraph just above the title [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#cors-policy-providers).

Does it work if you set `origins` to something specific?

Also is the request failing when the client hits the `/token` endpoint or when it hits a real endpoint after authorization has occurred?

If it fails hitting your `/token` endpoint, then you need to uninstall `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` and instead install `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` use that instead.